# li size to same as text's size

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm creating my custom menu with ul/li but I'm having problems with the size.

1. It does overflow to both sides left and right. To the left, when the element is scaled it does run out of parent element.
2. It does occupy the entire size as parent element, I want to li's size be same as li's text length so that the orange background is exactly same as text.

I tried

`width:100%;` and `width:auto;`

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <ul class="icon">
                                <li class="info">aaaaaa</li>
                                <li class="info">bbbbb</li>
                                <li class="info">cccccccccccc</li>
                                <li class="info">ddd</li>
                            </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.icon { 
    padding-left:20px; 
    list-style:none; 
}

li.icon { 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
}

ul.icon li:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.icon li.info:before {
    content: "->";
    color: green;
}

ul.icon li:hover {
         cursor: pointer;
         cursor: hand;
         background-color: rgb(242, 105, 34);
}

li.info {
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

li.info:hover {
    font-style: italic;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

[Live](https://jsfiddle.net/pr7fazxx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `display: inline-block` on the `:hover` and add `clear: both` and `float: left` to `li.info`, like this:

```
li.info {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

li.info:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: italic;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It should work normally, as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pr7fazxx/2/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:inline-block` on `:hover`, plus I've fixed your CSS code, due to of a rewriting of same classes among other minor issues .

```css
.icon {
  padding-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
.info {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 0 10px 20px
}
.info:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "->";
  color: green;
}
.info:hover {
  font-style: italic;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: hand;
  background-color: rgb(242, 105, 34);
}
```

```html
<ul class="icon">
  <li class="info">aaaaaa</li>
  <li class="info">bbbbb</li>
  <li class="info">cccccccccccc</li>
  <li class="info">ddd</li>
</ul>
```